# SignalR broadcast on specific clients

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

I have a notification system, using mvc 3, the system will send a notification to specific client when a new issue is opened for that user. User must be logged in to see these notifications, this is ok but how do i know which user to send?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure SignalR to use a specific client id - you could use the id generated by your membership provider for example.  Then when you want to broadcast to a specific user you can use the id from your membership provider (or however you have generated a unique id).